# GROUP BY, Sorting results futher

Tags: sql, group-by

Ok so I have a group by function,
Group By Y.

There are 5 different values the grouping could be: A, B, C, D, E.
How would I go about then grouping values that are the same, by another value, so if I have 2 data values returning as A, how do I group them futher?

```
GROUP BY Y
GROUP BY X (WHERE column1=column1)?
```

Comment: a) Try to at least be consistent - in your narrative, we have `A,B,C,D,E`, yet in your code sample, we have `X` and `Y`. b) Try to give some sample data and expected results. I've no idea what you're actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: Also, your title suggests a confusion of ideas - sorting and grouping are two entirely independent concepts. The fact that most SQL products will perform a sort in order to produce a grouped result is an implementation artifact. The order of results (absent an `ORDER BY` clause) is completely arbitrary, and could change at any time.

Answer (score 4):

You can just add multiple columns separated by `,`

```
select a, b, c, avg(d)
from mytable
group by a, b, c;
```